# Openlayers 3 Why a georeferenced image is badly placed in recent OL3 releases?

Tags: gis, openlayers-3

Some time ago I was developing educational pages for students in oceanography. One application consists in exploring satellite observations. The application renders a SST (Sea Surface Temperature) map of the Western Mediterranean basin. In openlayers v3.3.0 the rendering was perfect while in the new version v3.15.1 the rendering is very bad. The code is very simple, a base layer and a Image layer with a source.ImageStatic:

```
function init() {  
  var base = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'sat' })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [base],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([10.0, 41.0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
      opacity: 0.75,
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
       url: '/temporal/20130504.1337.n19.png',
       imageExtent: ol.extent.applyTransform([-15.006540,35.004948,16.493460, 46.504948],ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857")),
        imageSize: [2048,1166],
        projection: map.getView().getProjection()
       })
  });

  map.addLayer(imageLayer);     
}
```

The problem arises arises at least after v3.7.0 release. I have prepared an example for different versions:

- v3.3.0 at [v.330](http://www.physocean.icm.csic.es/temporal/k.330.html)
- v3.7.0 at [v.370](http://www.physocean.icm.csic.es/temporal/k.370.html)
- v3.14.0 at [v.3140](http://www.physocean.icm.csic.es/temporal/k.3140.html)
- v3.15.1 at [v.3151](http://www.physocean.icm.csic.es/temporal/k.3151.html)
- v3.16.0 at [v.3160](http://www.physocean.icm.csic.es/temporal/k.3160.html)

All have the same code above and only differ in the `ol.js` version.

Can anyone tell me if it is a bug of the new releases or I'm missing something evident ?

Comment: Time to give a feedback?

Comment: The explanation by ahocevar clearly answered my question. Unfortunately my typo was simultaneous with a bug in v.3.3.0 That's why I was disconcerted when updating my code using new releases.  @ahocevar kindly anwser me through Github site where I also tried to look for help . Thank you folks for your great and nice work to develop and improve OL3.

Comment: @user1259970 if the answer provided is helpful, it would be nice to accept it, to give the deserved feedback and reputation to the answerer.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your `imageSize` value. The width of your image is 2408 pixels, not 2048. There was a bug in older OpenLayers so the `imageSize` was ignored. Recent versions pick it up correctly, and so your typo causes the misalignment. The correct layer definition is

```
var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  opacity: 0.75,
  source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    url: '/temporal/20130504.1337.n19.png',
    imageExtent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-15.006540, 35.004948, 16.493460, 46.504948], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    imageSize: [2408, 1166]
  })
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/wsyroL3d/ for a working demo with v3.16.0.